# What is the best method fitting percentage data with a FEW zeros (linear mixed effects model)? Diagnostic plots

Tags: mixed-model, modeling, linear-model, random-effects-model, percentage

I have a few questions regarding a model fitted. A few things about the design. I have 10 treatments and 6 blocks (reps) in a RCBD design. I have had no trouble at all before fitting a linear mixed effects model. But with this dataset I do have a few zeros, not a lot. A total of 6 values with a percentage of 0 which makes the diagnostic plots look a little bad.

The response variable of interest is a disease rating percent (ranging from 0-100%). These are whole "pot" ratings of diseased plants. The response variable is called a disease severity index percent. In field trials diagnostic plots looked good because even in control plots there was still disease. But in greenhouse trials it is a very controlled environment so no disease is found on the control. The percentage data ranges from (0-63 %) in this case. A total of 6 treatments and 6 blocks in RCBD design totally 36 pots.

I set "treatment/isolate" as factor and block as a factor and fit a linear mixed effects model taking the form of....

I like to make interactions plots so you can see the dataset I am working with.

[image]

I fit a linear mixed effects model with block as a random effect and treatment as a fixed effect (as.factor). [image]

Here are my diagnostic plots.
[image]

I have tried possible transformations, but they have not worked with this dataset. I noticed I have a high CV assuming its because I have low or same values for the control while the other are high.

My questions are...

1. should I be using a different model? Even though I do not have a lot of zeros, only a few. If so what possible models should I try to fit that will allow a random effect of block.
2. Should I just report issue is normality and variance in methods due to zero values and move on. I could use the advise. The normal plot actually looks decent with a few outliers in the tails due to possible zero values. However I could report issues of non constant variance.

I would appreciate any advise. It is not a big dataset. A total of (6 treatments and 6 blocks = 36 entries)

Here is a brief summary of estimated means and SE from lsmeans function output.

[image]

Comment: Your control values are all zero, am I correct? Like those zeros were not observed, they are just structural?Those are not bona fide observations, and should not be in the dataset. The reason for the bad diagnostics is not those zeros, it is because some blocks have a lot more variation than others. No transformation can make that go away.

Comment: @RussLenth Yes! The controls are all zero observed values of disease. Based on the summary output of the model, there is little deviation in block. For block I have a standard deviation of 0.0001885282 with Residual standard deviation of 5.000168. From the Diagnostics the "Normal Plot for Random Intercept," show that the six blocks fall along the normal line quite well. Should I try to analyze the data set without zero values for control? But then my overall p-value would not not reflect the whole dataset I would think and I could not run a Tukey's post hoc test with all treatments.